# How to Store images downloaded from the web in cache?

Tags: android, android-listview

I m parsing some images and showing it in list view... but whenever i scroll it up and down it is just disappearing ...Can it be solved by storing it in cache... And if it is possible please suggest me the way,.... thank you...

Answer (score 3):

ya you can store it, you can use the concept of **LazyList** [**see**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012)